# Angular 2 / Typescript - TypeError: ClassName is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular

I am learning Angular 2 and I ran into this error while trying to create a service. I tried searching for a solution, but I cannot see my mistake.

**Error:**

```
angular2-polyfills.js:1243 TypeError: Tweet is not a constructor
```

**Code:**

```
export class TweetService{
    getTweets(){
        return tweets;
    }
}

let tweets = new Tweet("URL", "Author 1", "Handle 1", true, 50);

class Tweet {
    image: string;
    author: string;
    handle: string;
    status: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.";
    isLiked: boolean;
    favorites: number;

    constructor(img, aut, hndl, ilkd, fav){
        img = this.image;
        aut = this.author;
        hndl = this.handle;
        ilkd = this.isLiked;
        fav = this.favorites;        
    }
}
```

Comment: I've check your code here https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ and all compiles fine

Comment: Just clutching at straws here but did you try to export the Tweet class?

Comment: @VasiliyVanchuk Which makes is strange. :)

Comment: @Oli I don't think that is the problem. I tried it, but it didn't fix it.

Comment: Ok, then  we can rule that out atleast.

Comment: Plus one for broken export. Did you check what is 'Tweet' at string with error? ( I mean debugger )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your let statement is floating outside the class declarations. This will work (but in an real app you would be setting your tweets based on some http call or something):

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TweetService{
    getTweets(){
        let tweets = new Tweet("URL", "Author 1", "Handle 1", true, 50);
        return tweets;
    }
}

class Tweet {
    image: string;
    author: string;
    handle: string;
    status: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.";
    isLiked: boolean;
    favorites: number;

    constructor(img, aut, hndl, ilkd, fav){
        this.image = img;
        this.author = aut;
        this.handle = hndl;
        this.isLiked = ilkd;
        this.favorites = fav;        
    }
}
```

Comment: You are correct sir. This fixed the issue. About the http calls, I am currently learning Angular 2 and local repositories are more practical. Once I get better, I will use a RESTful API. Thank you.